# Could not invoke StripeSdk.initialise

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments, payment, google-pay

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMGIq.png)

I'm not able to start Stripe in react native using expo

```
const [prepared, setPrepared] = useState(false);
const [isAvaliable, setAvaliable] = useState(false);

const {
    isGooglePaySupported,
    initGooglePay,
} = useGooglePay();

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await LoadFonts();
        await initStripe({publishableKey: "my_key"})

        setPrepared(true);
    })();
}, []);
```

I want to integrate the Google Pay payment method

Comment: I believe you will need to include more code and information to receive an answer.

Comment: You can find more details on enabling Google Pay with Stripe using React Native here: https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native